# Bundle update is run but gem is not showing up in gem folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I have included gem 'actionpack' in my gemfile. I then run bundle install.

When I run 'gem list' I see 'actionpack'.

However when I go to /Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0 I don't see a folder for actionpack.

I keep getting this error

```
Sharats-MacBook-Pro:reflections sharatakasapu$ rails s
/Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'actionpack' (= 5.1.7) among 275 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/sharatakasapu/.gem/ruby/2.4.0:/Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1428:in `each'
    from /Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1428:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1410:in `activate'
    from /Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:299:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    from /Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:299:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:299:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'actionpack'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.2.4'
gem 'devise'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 6.0'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

How do I address this?

Comment: just added my gemfile @dbugger

Comment: actionpack should be directly installed with the rails gem -- there is no need to add it separately

Comment: hm I'm not sure how to fix this then as I get the same error

Comment: sorry for the dumb question but how do I kill the lock file?

Comment: I deleted the file, ran 'bundle update' again, and then 'rails s' and receive the same error :(

Comment: Where is your ruby version specified?  And what version are you using?

Comment: Also might want to replace your gitsource block with this 
`git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }`

Comment: ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]

how do I find out where the version is specified?

Comment: Usually specified at the top of the gem file, immediately after the source
ruby '2.6.3'

Comment: I'm realizing I don't have a ruby version specified in the gemfile itself.